# flask run does not work but python server.py does! Environment vars set

Tags: python, flask

When I try to run my very simple Flask application using `flask run` it does not work but when I `cd src` and `python server.py` it does work.

File structure:

```
my_project
|____init__.py
|
|__src
|  |____init__.py
|  |__server.py
|  |__chat.py
|
|__test
|  |____init__.py
|  |__test_server.py
|  |__test_chat.py
|
|__FLASK_ENV_VARS.sh
```

`server.py`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import chat

api = Flask(__name__)


@api.route('/')
def root():
    message = chat.say_hello()
    return jsonify(message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(debug=True)
```

In order to get the tests to pass, I need to `from src import chat`. When I leave it as `import chat` the server runs when I try `python server.py` but not `flask run` (which doesn't run either way of importing chat). Interestingly, I get a red squggly line under chat from my IDE when `import chat` that goes away with `from src import chat`.

`test_server.py`

```
import pytest


from src.server import api


def test_route(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    expected_data = b'{"message":"Welcome message here"}\n'
    assert response.data == expected_data



@pytest.fixture
def client():
    api.testing = True
    client = api.test_client()
    return client
```

The content of the environment variables shell script is

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
export FLASK_APP=server.py
```

I have tried making `FLASK_APP` both `src.server.py` and `server.py`, neither currently works. Of course I remember to run the shell script and echo the variables to ensure that they have changed.

The error I get from `flask run` is `flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "my_project.server".`

When I `cd src` and `flask run` I get `flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "my_project.src.server", an ImportError was raised:`

The problem, I suspect lies with the way chat is imported. The tests only run with `from src import chat`. When I run `python server.py` I have to have only `import chat` or it doesn't work. I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat'` as part of the stack trace or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` depending on which style of import was used. I'm not sure what I am getting wrong here. I am inclined to think that `from src import chat` is correct since this is what makes the tests pass, however I can't get this to work at all.

Comment: I changed export FLASK_APP=server.py to export FLASK_APP=./src/server.py and it worked.

Comment: Alas, I still get `flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "my_project.src.server", an ImportError was raised:` ‍♀️

Comment: I also got the same error initially, but started working when i changed FLASK_APP to "./src/server.py". After exporting the env_variables manually, i ran "flask run" from "my_project" directory. Was this what you did?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is the line that fails `from src import chat`. I think that the `FLASK_APP` environment variable might be a red herring. I think there is something wonky with the import

Comment: Okay, what part of the code is this? I worked with what you posted. The only import for "chat" is in the server.py file, and it is like this "import chat"

Comment: It works like `import chat` perfectly when I run `python server.py` rather than `flask run`, however the tests only pass when I use `from src import chat`.

Comment: I modified the following files; server.py to - "from my_project.src import chat" and test_server.py to - "from my_project.src.server import api". After that, "flask run" works and pytest returned "test/test_server.py:10: AssertionError".

Comment: Thank you, `from my_project.src import chat` makes both `flask run` and the tests work as expected.

Comment: Scrap that! it isn't working again. Have absolutely no idea why. It was earlier. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$env:FLASK_APP = "server.py"`

try Something like this too , `export FLASK_APP=my_project/src/server.py; flask run`

You can also mention `app = Flask (__name__) in __init__.py and then execute flask run`

Comment: No I hadn't. 
Alas, `bash: export: \`server.py': not a valid identifier` when part of the shell script or 
`bash: :FLASK_APP: command not found` directly in the command line

Comment: Thanks for your comments, friend. Unfortunately these don't solve my problem.